# Google Apps Script - adding in array elements

Tags: arrays, math, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a begginer ok... I'm trying to use math operators in array elements, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I used the parseInt and Number function to increment array elements with some integers, but it's not working.

The **original values** from my sheet are:
[[1000.0], [1000.0], [3000.0], [1000.0], [], [], [], [], [], []]

When I tryed **without parseInt/Number** the result was:
[01000100030001000, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

When I tryed **with parseInt/Number**:
[NaN, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

```
function myFunction() {
  var ssCDB = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CDB");
  var cdbRange = ssCDB.getRange(3, 3, 10, 1).getValues();

  var cdbSum = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

  Logger.log(cdbRange);

  for (var i=0; i<cdbRange.length; i++) {
     cdbSum[0] = cdbSum[0] + cdbRange[i];
    //cdbSum[0] = parseInt(cdbSum[0]) + parseInt(cdbRange[i]);
  }

  Logger.log(cdbSum);
}
```

I'm expecting something like: [**6000.0**, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

what am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: What'll be the value of  `cdbRange[i]` during  first iteration?

Comment: Why do you need an array for cbdSum?  Try var cbdSum = 0; then in your loop cdbSum = cdbSum + cdbRange[i][0]; since sdbRange is a 2D array [[].[],[]...].  i is each row and 0 is the first (and only) cell in the array.

Comment: thanks @TheWizEd, I changed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are 3 issues for your situation.

1. `cdbRange` is 2 dimensional array. But you are using it like `cdbRange[i]`.

   - In this case, `cdbRange[0]` is `[1000.0]` which is an object.
2. By `cdbSum[0] = cdbSum[0] + cdbRange[i]`, `cdbSum[0]` is used as a string value. Because `cdbRange[i]` is an object. When it adds an object to a number, it becomes the string type.

   - This is the reason of `01000100030001000`. The initial value of `cdbSum[0]` is `0`.
3. Value in the element of index of 4 to 9 of `cdbRange` is `undefined`.

   - When these are summed, the result becomes `NaN`.

In order to avoid these issues, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
cdbSum[0] = cdbSum[0] + cdbRange[i];
```

#### To:

```
if (cdbRange[i][0]) cdbSum[0] += cdbRange[i][0];
```

or

```
if (cdbRange[i][0]) cdbSum[0] += Number(cdbRange[i][0]);
```

#### Result:

```
[6000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

#### Note:

- I understood that you want to add the sum of all elements of `cdbRange` to `cdbSum[0]`.

#### References:

- [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)
- [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: hey @Tanaike, thanks! It helped me a lot. Especially regarding cdbRange ... is a multidimensional array and I did not even notice it. I only changed **cdbRange[i][0]**.

Comment: @Elder Souza Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vA=sh.getRange(3,3,10,1).getValues();
  var sumA=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
     sumA[i]+=vA[i][0];//a 1 column 2d array
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(sumA.join(', ')), 'Sum');//Do not need this it just show your sum values
}
```